# jq use value of if to concatinate and get a 3rd value of key to be deleted

Tags: jq

I have a jq statement that works https://jqplay.org/s/GD739UVIv-x, but is deleting the wrong key.

```
//original json 
{
    "dog": {
        "alpha": "one",
        "gamma": "square"
    },
    "square": {
        "circle": {
            "triangle": "sides3"
        }
    },
    "sides3": "delete me"
}
```

so the flow should be

```
if 
   dog.beta exists =>  $new_key_a = value of beta
   delete key matching value of beta 
 elif
   dog.gamma exists => $new_key_a = value of [gamma].circle.triangle (sides3)
   delete key "sides3"
```

the below `.[$new_key_a].circle.triangle` gets me to `sides3` value, but not sure how to include it in the `if` statement

```
first(.. | objects | select(.alpha? == "one") | if (.beta) then .beta else .gamma  end) as $new_key_a | .[$new_key_a].circle.triangle
```

is it possible to use the output of the `if` to concatenate to use a 3rd value, such as,

if `.gamma` is selected, then use the value of `.gamma` to get a nested value, such as `[$gamma].circle.triangle as $new_key_a`, so the del function would remove the value of  `square.circle.triangle` not the object `square`, but only if `.beta` is not found

`first(.. | objects | select(.alpha? == "one") | if (.beta) then .beta else .gamma end) as $new_key_a | del(.. | .[$new_key_a]? | select(.))`

```
//expected output
{
    "dog": {
        "alpha": "one",
        "gamma": "square"
    },
    "square": {
        "circle": {
            "triangle": "sides3"
        }
    }
}
```

tried various combinations of below, but this is obviously on the wrong track as I have not declared $gamma.

```
else [$gamma].circle.triangle
```

Comment: Seems like your filter can be improved even more. Would help if you could clearly describe what you're trying to achieve with your filter.

Comment: TLDR: concat a value of a key to get another nested value based on an if condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if this is what you asked for, but you could just append the next path before binding the variable. Along with some other simplifications I get:

```bash
.[first(.. | objects | select(.alpha == "one") | .beta // .gamma)]
  .circle.triangle as $new_key_a | del(.. | .[$new_key_a]?)
```

Update: considering the clarification that `.circle.triangle` should be appended only to `.gamma`, not to `.beta`, carry out the appended information to top-level (e.g. using a paths array), then realize its evaluation outside (e.g. using `getpath`):

```bash
getpath(first(
  .. | objects | select(.alpha == "one")
  | if .beta then [.beta] else [.gamma, "circle", "triangle"] end
)) as $new_key_a
| del(.. | .[$new_key_a]?)
```

```json
{
  "dog": {
    "alpha": "one",
    "gamma": "square"
  },
  "square": {
    "circle": {
      "triangle": "sides3"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you almost got what I was asking. the only difference is `.circle.triangle` should only be attached to `gamma`, not to `beta`. From what I understand of your answer this is applying `circle.triangle` to both - is that correct? if so i need something like `.beta // .gamma.circle.triangle ]) as ...`

Comment: @artvanderlay Yes, it did. I added another one considering your clarification.

Comment: this definitely works according to the question. Thanks for wading through the details to get to the answer.    Is it also possible to add error handling as well in case neither .beta or .gamma exists , such as `... [.gamma, "circle", "triangle"]?`

Comment: @artvanderlay In this case I'd bind the variable before evaluation, and add some default value (e.g. using `elif` and `null`), as in `(first(… | if .beta then [.beta] elif .gamma then [.gamma, "circle", "triangle"] else null end) // null) as $new_path_a` (the `else null` is set if neither `.beta` nor `.gamma` are truthy, the `// null` if `first` has no output at all), then with another `if` you can perform either the intended action or do the error handling, e.g. `… | if $new_path_a then getpath($new_path_a) as $new_key_a | del(.. | .[$new_key_a]?) else "error handling" end`.

Comment: damm, I was so close to getting this my self thanks to your answers on other questions. I did not have the additional `// null)`. is this needed as I think i get the same results without adding it, just using ` ... else null end))`?

Comment: @artvanderlay It's not strictly needed, it just tests for another edge case. If you omit it, nothing will happen if `.alpha == "one"` can't even once be statisfied (that's literally nothing, like with `empty`, i.e. no output and no error handling). The `null` from `else` will still come through (if reached), and your error handling will be processed if there was (at least) one item where `.alpha == "one"`, and neither `.beta` nor `.gamma` were truthy.